# After resolution change hidden animated window is transparent

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am animating a window's opacity

...

```
  DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation =
          new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25)), FillBehavior.Stop);
  Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, "wndNumpad");
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Window.OpacityProperty));
  m_fadeOut = new Storyboard();
  m_fadeOut.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
  m_fadeOut.Completed += new EventHandler(FadeOut_Completed);
```

...

```
private void FadeOut_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //  Only hide the running instance
  this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
  // this.Close();
}
```

If the screen resolution of a monitor is changed after FadeOut_Completed() has run i.e. the window's opacity was animated and the window is hidden. Then reshowing the window will display the window almost transparent. At a guess I would say with the opacity it had when the window was hidden although the Window.Opacity property claims an opacity of 1. If I don't animate but simply set the opacity to 0 and hide the window and after the resolution change set the opacity back to 1 the window is reshown as expected. I have also tried setting the opacity back to 1 in the FadeOut_Completed.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening and how I can avoid the issue?

Regards
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You must to have a transparent window (`AllowsTransparency="True"`), no-resizable (`ResizeMode="NoResize"`) and with no border (`WindowStyle="None"`). In C# code, I created a `DoubleAnimation` that change the opacity of the window, and when it is complete, the window will be closed.

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Red" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = 1;
            da.To = 0;
            da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            da.Completed += new EventHandler(da_Completed);
            this.BeginAnimation(OpacityProperty, da);
        }

        void da_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the above is basically the same as in the question. If I were to uncomment the this.Close() in my  FadeOut_Completed() event handler it would indeed close after fading away. The window is instead hidden because of the speed WPF apps load "unacceptable" seems to be the appropriate word. The issue with the fading and the screen resolution change is that only a "shadow" of the window is re-shown although the opacity is supposedly back at 1.